# Concatenate one column of one df to all columns of another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables `df1` and `df2`.

```
print(df1)
    bar foo doo
0    a   e   h
1    b   f   i
2    c   g   j

print(df2)
    zoo
0    x
1    y
2    z
```

I need to concatenate column `zoo` in `df2` with each column of `df1`.

I need this table:

```
     bar   foo   doo
0    a x   e x   h x
1    b y   f y   i y
2    c z   g z   j z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use:

```
df1.add(' ' + df2['zoo'], axis=0)

   bar  foo  doo
0  a x  e x  h x
1  b y  f y  i y
2  c z  g z  j z
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with :

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x+' '+df2.zoo)
```

---

```
   bar  foo  doo
0  a x  e x  h x
1  b y  f y  i y
2  c z  g z  j z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
for col in list(df1.columns):
    df1[col] = df1[col] + ' ' + df2['Zoo']
```